# ORACLE REGEXP_SUBSTR that match digits between square brackets

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a VARCHAR column that no have specific format.

These are some examples:

```
afdsbfgf, jbhttp://www.iabvdfbdos.com/view.php?p_id=170405, arcm, cocm, fbus, bv[123545]
```

I need to match the substring between brackets when the string is like 'bv[123545]'. This substring is always numeric.

I tried it like that:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (my_column, '[^bv\[]+[[:digit:]]+')
```

But this also matches with

```
'jbhttp://www.iabvdfbdos.com/view.php?p_id=170405' and returns "_id=170405"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: but i didn't find any brackets in your input.

Comment: sorry I meant square brackets: My input can be like: bv[123545]. I need obtain the digits between the square brackets: 123545

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR (my_column, 'bv\[]([[:digit:]]+)')` . Get the num from group index 1.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes the brackets only appear once in the line.  It grabs the first sub-group (the part in the parens) of the first occurrence of 'bv' followed by a left square bracket, followed by one or more digits, followed by a right square bracket.  The square brackets are escaped as they define a character class in the regex engine otherwise.

```
SQL> select regexp_substr('afdsbfgf, jbhttp://www.iabvdfbdos.com/view.php?p_id=170405, arcm, cocm, fbus, bv[123545]', 'bv\[(\d+)\]', 1, 1, null, 1 ) from dual;

REGEXP
------
123545

SQL>
```